# PHP Radio Button Secure When Emailing

Tags: php, html, checkbox, radio-button

I've been trying to figure out if radio buttons and checkboxes need to be stripped (cleaned?) when sending them via email and how to do so.

I have a contact form that just emails the information. It doesn't touch a database. Do I need to protect the radio buttons and checkboxes when emailing? Is it possible?

I haven't found anything on google regarding securing these when emailing them. I keep coming across a few answers that say that should definitely be protected when sending to a database. The same is found here, or questions regarding how to grab values or create one dynamically. So, I'm at a loss.

Do I secure radio buttons and checkboxes when emailing? Is it possible? Necessary? If so, how do I do it?

Here's what my code looks like, partially:

```
    $firstName = strip_tags($_POST['firstName']);
    $lastName = strip_tags($_POST['lastName']);
    $email = strip_tags($_POST['emailAddress']);
    $telNum = strip_tags($_POST['phoneNumber']);
    $colors= $_POST['eColors'];
    $additionalComments = strip_tags($_POST['additionalComments']);
    $spamField = strip_tags($_POST['sField']);


    <form id="contact-form" action="" method="post">

    <div>
            <input type="text" id="nameFirst" name="firstName" /> 
            <label for="nameFirst" class="nameIcon">
                <span>First Name</span>
            </label>
            <span class="hint">
                <p>Input hint goes here</p>
            </span>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="text" id="nameLast" name="lastName" />
            <label for="nameLast" class="nameIcon">
                <span>Last Name</span>
            </label>
            <span class="hint">
                <p>Input hint goes here</p>
            </span>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="email" id="eAddy" name="emailAddress" />
            <label for="eAddy" class="emailIcon">
                <span>Contact Email</span>
            </label>
            <span class="hint">
                <p>Input hint goes here</p>
            </span>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="tel" id="telNum" name="phoneNumber" />
            <label for="telNum" class="contactIcon">
                <span>Contact Number</span>
            </label>
            <span class="hint">
                <p>Input hint goes here</p>
            </span>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="cbEColors" name="eColors" class="cbSwitch" />
            <label for="cbEColors">Do you expect more color?</label>
        </div>

        <div>
            <textarea id="addComments" name="additionalComments"></textarea>
            <label for="addComments" class="messageIcon">
                <span>Additional Comments</span>
            </label>
            <span class="hint">
                <p>Input hint goes here</p>
            </span>
        </div>

        <input type="text" id="sField" class="col" name="sField" />

        <button id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>

    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I follow a simple but critical rule for PHP security: never trust input values, regardless of their expected type or external validation (eg client side browser validation).

There is a great article on this [here](http://phpsecurity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Input-Validation.html).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Do you by any chance know how to secure a radio button or checkbox? I know general inputs use strip_tags. IE `strip_tags($_POST['phoneNumber']);` How do I do that for the other two? Also, yes, that is helpful and I've bookmarked it so I have it. Thank you.

Comment: The answer to that could vary depending on what possible checkbox values are allowed. Personally I would define an array of accepted values for the field, and do something like:  $checkboxValue =  (!empty($_POST['checkboxInput']) && in_array($_POST['checkboxInput'], $acceptedValues)) ? $_POST['checkboxInput'] : null;

Which checks if the input has a value and if that value is in the array of accepted values. If those conditions are met, $checkboxValue is assigned the value of what was sent, otherwise is set to null.

Comment: I just found that in a search. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First off, the correct term is sanitized. (You were close)

Also, to be on the safe side, I would. Remember that people can change an input from a checkbox to an input. Even though you aren't submitting this to a database, what if one day you decide to? You will most likely forget about that whole and all of a sudden your production database is compromised.

To make a long post short, yes.

Comment: Thank you. That cut my searching down a great deal.